# SQL Server query with case in select statement with multiple INNER JOINS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, case, inner-join

I have a query with returns a set of data about projects. The issue however is that some of the projects don't have a valid currency id.

So i'm trying to build a query that will, if the currency id is 0, use the id 140 instead. This is what I have so far but returns no results if the currency id is 0.

```
   SELECT *,
   CASE
   WHEN p.currencyid=0 THEN 140
   END
   FROM projects AS p 
   INNER JOIN businesssectors AS bs ON bs.businesssectorid=p.businesssectorid 
   INNER JOIN currencies AS c ON c.currencyid=p.currencyid
   INNER JOIN plants AS pl ON p.plantid=pl.plantid 
   WHERE p.projectid='195'
```

Comment: I believe you missing else part

Comment: @apomene Thanks, I tried it with this case statement CASE
      WHEN p.currencyid=0 THEN 140
   ELSE p.currencyid
   END and still get nothing back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should work

```
   SELECT *,
   CASE
   WHEN p.currencyid=0 THEN 140 ELSE p.currencyid 
   END
   FROM projects AS p 
   INNER JOIN businesssectors AS bs ON bs.businesssectorid=p.businesssectorid 
   INNER JOIN plants AS pl ON p.plantid=pl.plantid 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN currencies AS c ON c.currencyid=p.currencyid
   WHERE p.projectid='195'
```

Comment: Not sure if they want a value for currency returned when p.currencyid is not 0. If so, just need to add an else to the case expression.